# fatal error: Array index out of range Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In this example, I am creating a new empty array of `Int` and I want to add certain characters from the other array into it. Originally, in my `characters` array I store numbers `["1","","2","","3"]` and in this array (I might be doing this completely wrong) I want to iterate through those numbers to produce a `newarray` which will have these numbers `[1,2,3]` (essentially removing the spaces in between and making them of type `Int`)

As far as I understand, I have created a dynamic array i.e. no specific size, but I am getting this error : `fatal error: Array index out of range` and I am not sure why. Could someone clarify this for me? Thanks

```
 do{
        var data = try String(contentsOfFile: documentsDirectoryPath as String,
            encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        print(data)
        let characters = Array(data.characters)
        print(characters)
        var newarray = [Int]()

        for var index = 0; index <= characters.count ; ++index {
            if characters[index] == " " {
                index++
            }
            else{
                newarray[index] = index
            }
        }
        print(newarray)    
    }
    catch{

        print("error")
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you know at what line you get this error, did you step through the code?

Comment: yes its here : `newarray[index] = index`

Comment: Your problem is (partly) `if characters[index] == " " {index++}`. You're incrementing twice if this happens. The for loop already increments the value for you. Also a nicer way of writing the loop would be `for index in 0..<characters.count {}`. As also pointed out, you should use `append` to add items to your new array.

Comment: Are `1, 2, 3` in the output have anything to do with `"1", "2", "3"` from the input? Would output from `["A", " ", "B", " ", "C"]` array be any different?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well, I was hoping to convert those `"1", "2", "3"` into integers hence why i removed the `" "` in my output. I am only storing numbers in that array but in `String` type for now. So your `["A", " ", "B", " ", "C"]` for this particular scenario would be `["A", "B", "C"]` but I want to store only `Integers` so that wouldn't work in my case

Comment: @user3395936 Would you store single-digit integers, or multidigit integers are allowed as well?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thats a good point actually, I didnt think of that :)  I think for what I want to do both are acceptable

Comment: @user3395936 so for `["1", "2", "", "3", "4"]` you expect to get `[12, 34]`? If the answer is "yes", then your approach is invalid.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well the whole point of me doing this in this complicated for loop was to check if there is a `" "` in the array, if yes ignore and dont add it into the new array, otherwise add the number into the new array. From your output, my system would produce `[1,2,3,4]` and it would ignore that space in the centre. Another example would be having these numbers `["12","54","34", "134556" , " ", " ", " ", "1"]` the output would be `[12,54,34,134556,1]`. Hope this is clearer

Comment: @user3395936 But you convert your file to an array of characters, how `"134556"` be in there? What about commas? Could you post the content of your file verbatim, along with spaces and all other allowable characters? Put four spaces in front of it for the formatting to look OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing from your other comments in this thread it appears you are trying to filter out **spaces** and **commas** from a string that may look like `"1, 2, 3"`. Correct me if this is wrong. The completely *swifty* solution to this is as follows:

```
do {
    var data = try String(contentsOfFile: documentsDirectoryPath as String, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    print(data)

    let newarray = data.characters.filter { Int(String($0)) != nil }.map { Int(String($0))! }    
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

#### Explanation

`filter` will return an array of `Character`s that convert to integers. `map` will then take that array and then transform each element into an integer. We have to convert the `Character` to a `String` type because there is no `Int` constructor that takes a `Character`.

Comment: You should also probably just change the filter condition to `Int(String($0)) != nil`. That way there's no chance of a force unwrapping of `nil` in the map. This is the correct answer though.

Comment: Makes it feel a bit redundant with the same statement in both closures but I see your point. I'll edit it.

Comment: Wow the only answer that helped, thank you so much. Although it gave me a slight error, so I used @originaluser2 's suggestion and it worked like a charm

Comment: @Slayter may i also ask, if I for example I have a number which is a double for example `["1.2","2","3"]`, I won't be able to achieve the same logic with the code you have provided am i right? (I mean `[1.2,2,3]`)

Comment: As far as I know (someone else can correct this) Swift arrays can only hold one data type. Therefore you would have to make them all `Double`s then attempt to convert the integer values to `Int`s later if you need to.

Comment: @Slayter the thing is when I try to convert them into double , i.e. `["1.2","3","4"]` the output produced is this `["1.0","2.0","3.0","4.0"]`. Is there a way to solve this, or am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help by the way, I appreciate it

Comment: If you look at his code, you see that the `String`s are casted as an `Int`. So, try casting them as a `Double`.

Comment: @Slayter One more thing I noticed, when I supply an integer with two or more digits, it doesn't recognise it as a whole number so for example when I have `[100,1]` the output is `[1,0,0,1]` . Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: @user3395936 that's probably because the filter call goes character by character. Off the top of my head I don't have a solution but I would look into the `split` function and see if that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code, most important of which is that your approach is incorrect, because it treats a string as a collection of individual characters, while your problem calls for parsing multi-digit numbers.

A better approach is to split the array on commas, and parse integers from trimmed results, like this:

```
let data = "12, 23, 345"
print(data)
let newarray = data.characters.split(){$0 == ","}.map{
    Int(String.init($0).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()))!
}
print(newarray) // 12, 23, 345
```

Comment: This is wrong, since he obviously wants to have 0 in places corresponding to spaces.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the exception, but thats not really what i am aiming to do. I want to replace the value at a particular index in my `new array` with the new `index`. For example in my `characters` array I have these numbers `["1"," ", "2", " ", "3"']` and i want my `newarray` to be `[1, 2, 3']`. The append gave me this output : `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: @s1ddok You are right, she wants to do similar to what you have described, but instead of 0's, just go to the next position in the array and iterate through blank spaces

Comment: So, you want to remove the empty members from the array?

Comment: @Koen correct, but not the empty numbers, just empty spaces in my `characters` array

Comment: @user3395936 then you are doing it absolutely wrong, since you adding indexes into your `newarray`, not characters. Try `append(characters[index])`

Comment: @user3395936 You should explain what you are trying to do in your question then, because the code that you have is too far from what you want to achieve. I made another guess at what you are trying to do, based on the input and the output. Note that the indexes in my output are one-based because of pre-increment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight again, the code you provided is not giving the output I require `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` .

Comment: That's because you didn't specify clearly what you "require".

Comment: @user3395936 Are you sure the input has proper space characters then? I mean, not tabs or some other whitespace, but `" "`? I get this output: `1 2 3
["1", " ", "2", " ", "3"]
[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `newarray` has no capacity.

Try using `append` method or create array with capacity like so:

`let newarray = [Int](count:charactes.count, repeatedValue: 0)`.

P.S. Also note that you have mistake in for loop, you should use `<`instead of `<=` and hustling with iterator value within the loop is a bad idea, you increment this var twice when you see a space, are you sure that is intended?

And you are using two bad practices in Swift. First of all, you use C-like for-loop which will be removed in Swift 3. Same goes for `++` operators. They will be removed too.

Use `for-in` and `+=` instead. This will make your code more Swift-ish.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you told in comments (you want to remove space chars from array and get the new one), you can achieve it like so:

`let newarray = characters.filter { $0 != " " }`

Comment: Your code is giving me this : `["1", ",", "2", ",", "3"]`

Comment: Well, correct the question then. You told us that you want to remove spaces from array, how would we know that you also don't want to be commas there. If you need to extract only numerical chars from array, then you should state it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

First remove all spaces from the `String`, then convert it to `Array`:

```
let trimmedData = data.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
let characters = Array(trimmedData.characters)
```

Edit: if you just want to keep the numbers:

```
let validNumbers = "1234567890"
let validSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: validNumbers)
let trimmedData = data.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(validSet)
let characters = Array(trimmedData.characters)
```

Comment: unfortunately getting this again `["1", ",", "2", ",", "3"]`

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
for var index = 0; index <= characters.count ; ++index {
```

to this one:

```
for var index = 0; index < characters.count ; ++index {
```